# Compare two slopes from regression in R

Tags: r

I used this code to get a plot with log formula

```
df %>%
  mutate(absVO2 = absVO2*1000) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = VE, y = absVO2, color = group)) +
  geom_point(size = 0.5) +
  geom_smooth(aes(colour=group), method = "lm", formula = y ~ log(x)) +
  stat_regline_equation(label.x = 25, label.y = c(2400,2800), 
                        formula = y ~ log(x),
                        aes(color = group, label =  paste(..eq.label.., ..adj.rr.label.., sep = "~~~~")),) +
  xlab("VE (L/min)") + 
  ylab(expression(paste("V", O[2]," (mL/min)"))) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 100), breaks = seq(0, 100, by = 25)) +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(
    panel.background = element_rect(fill ="white", colour = "white"),
    axis.line = element_line(colour = "black"),
    legend.title = element_text(face = "bold"),
    legend.position = "none",
    strip.text = element_blank()
  )
```

That gives me this output:
[image]

I would like to statistically compare the two slopes, i.e. `910` and `970` which are the `a` in the  `VO2 = a * log(VE) + b` formula.

Thank you!

Here are the data:

```
structure(list(VE = c(22.75, 23.75, 26.75, 32.5, 39.5, 48.25, 
55.75, 24, 26.5, 29, 36.5, 44.75, 55.25, 63.75, 78, 19, 20.75, 
25, 29, 39.25, 51, 25, 25.5, 28.5, 34.25, 35.5, 40.25, 47, 52.5, 
59.5, 64.5, 83, 92.25, 18.25, 19.75, 20.75, 23.5, 26.25, 28, 
32.75, 37.25, 24.25, 26.75, 29.5, 31, 32, 39, 43.25, 46.25, 51.75, 
52.75, 64.5, 72.75, 15.75, 16.25, 20.25, 28, 34.75, 45.75, 64.75, 
18.25, 21.25, 22.25, 24.75, 29.5, 21.25, 20.75, 26, 30.75, 34, 
38.5, 46.75, 53.75, 70.5, 82.75, 98.25, 17.25, 22, 25.75, 29.75, 
33.75, 38.75, 44.5, 50.75, 56.25, 65, 71.75, 81, 99, 30, 29, 
29.75, 38.25, 40.75, 47.25, 52.75, 65.5, 22.75, 24.75, 28.75, 
34, 48, 53.75, 61.5, 73.75, 22, 21.75, 24.25, 28, 34.5, 40, 48.5
), absVO2 = c(0.739, 0.81975, 0.95125, 1.07525, 1.199, 1.34575, 
1.49775, 0.66125, 0.7485, 0.855, 0.9845, 1.1495, 1.3465, 1.451, 
1.5985, 0.61675, 0.717, 0.86275, 0.98575, 1.13, 1.262, 0.8835, 
0.94575, 1.08125, 1.244, 1.30475, 1.4735, 1.679, 1.79075, 1.96, 
2.0405, 2.34425, 2.4435, 0.5925, 0.661, 0.7435, 0.87875, 0.9435, 
0.99675, 1.11425, 1.20275, 0.9255, 1.02925, 1.11675, 1.19725, 
1.24775, 1.42625, 1.54225, 1.59425, 1.69675, 1.776, 1.94525, 
2.0395, 0.535, 0.5845, 0.76875, 0.982, 1.09975, 1.259, 1.3265, 
0.7205, 0.86825, 0.9235, 1.01075, 1.17275, 0.7435, 0.76575, 0.96075, 
1.0975, 1.21975, 1.34525, 1.50625, 1.6755, 1.86325, 2.0465, 2.1395, 
0.613, 0.85525, 0.98, 1.076, 1.287, 1.4615, 1.59325, 1.6965, 
1.884, 1.998, 2.1425, 2.31275, 2.474, 0.81075, 0.8035, 0.8645, 
1.076, 1.119, 1.255, 1.33825, 1.499, 0.8105, 0.8865, 1.03725, 
1.134, 1.26675, 1.36275, 1.4455, 1.52875, 0.64675, 0.6645, 0.742, 
0.81675, 0.983, 1.06875, 1.155), group = c("CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", 
"Healthy", "Healthy", "Healthy", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", "CAD", 
"CAD", "CAD", "CAD")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -112L))
```

Comment: Build a linear model then you can compare the two.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but unfortunately, I am limited with my R skills ! :)

Comment: Share your data then, preferably using `dput`.

Comment: I just edited the question and provided data

Answer (score 0):

Your hypothesis is that the slope of two groups are different. To answer this you build a linear model with added group variable and an interaction between group and VE (without an interaction you are assuming the slope is the same between the groups, so you already have your answer in this case):

```
> summary(lm(absVO2*1000~group*log(VE),data=df))

Coefficients:
                     Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)          -2120.98     210.38 -10.081   <2e-16 ***
groupHealthy           -96.46     263.82  -0.366    0.715    
log(VE)                914.32      57.40  15.928   <2e-16 ***
groupHealthy:log(VE)    60.52      72.64   0.833    0.407
```

`Intercept` is the value of absVO2 when `log(VE)` is zero (not really meaningfull for your data) and `group = CAD` (which is the reference group, you can change this). `log(VE)` is the term you are interested in (the slope), which is approx. 914 for `group = CAD`, for `group = healthy` you have to add approx. 60 to it (which would result in a slope of approx. 974), but this coefficient is not significant (based on the PR(t) column - the dreaded p-value).

Comment: Thank you very much. do you mean `0.407` here ?

Comment: @MaxB Yes, that is the p-value of the difference in the slope of group healthy (compared to group CAD).

Comment: @MaxB Note: this is assuming the model is correct, that is that it fits the data. Looking at the diagnostic plots you will see there are some issues, so you will probably need to fix this in order for the results to be realistic.